# Find a python transformation function or numpy matrix to transform skewed normal distribution to normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have an input dataset (DataFrame / numpy matrix) that has a skewed normal distribution.  I am trying to find the python transformation function (or numpy matrix) which will transform the input dataset to a normal distribution with no skew.

I have looked at curve_fit (in scipy.optimize) and am not sure how I would go about applying it.

Is there a simple method of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done one of 2 things:

- Use [box-cox transformations](https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/making-data-normal-using-box-cox-power-transformation/).  This requires you find the appropriate power or lambda that transforms you data to having zero skew.
- Force a normal distribution.

---

Example

```
from scipy.stats import norm

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000), columns=['Uniform'])
df['Normal'] = norm.ppf((df.Uniform.rank() - .5) / len(df))
df.plot(kind='kde')
```

[image]

```
df.skew()

Uniform    2.392991e-02
Normal     2.114051e-15
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I was about to post Box-Cox. Scipy finds the lambda that maximizes the likelihood: http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html